# Unable to install Sonarlint on Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, sonarlint

I am trying to install Sonarlint on Eclipse. I am getting the below error:

```
No repository found at https://eclipse-uc.sonarlint.org.
```

Please help.

Comment: The Sonarlint update site is broken for me too. Maybe something went wrong with the update yesterday. Make sure it has been [reported to Sonarlint](https://community.sonarsource.com/c/bug/5).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're trying to install it on a relatively recent version of Eclipse (latest is 2020-09), you should just be able to open the Marketplace Client ("Help"->"Eclipse MarketPlace...") and enter "sonarlint" in the filter field, and install the "SonarLint" plugin that it finds.

Comment: I did it yesterday but did not work. After reading your comment, tried it and now working. Thank you. :-)